# PostgreSQL array_remove on BIGINT ARRAY

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to remove an item from a BIGINT Array, so naturally i tried :

```
update MyTABLE
set MyBigIntArray= array_remove(MyBigIntArray,1)
where id=10
```

but Postgresql (tried with 9.5 and 10.0 ) reply me :

> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts. ERROR: function
>   array_remove(bigint[], integer) does not exist

even if it normally accept anyarray : array_remove(anyarray, anyelement)
, src : [Postgres DOC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html)

The only thing that make it work is to cast my bigint[] to int[] like that :

```
update MyTABLE
set MyBigIntArray= array_remove(MyBigIntArray::int[],1)
where id=10
```

so is there a way to do that in a simple way ? (i found some plsql/SQL function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `1` to `bigint` too:

```
[local] #= SELECT array_remove(ARRAY[1::bigint], 1);
ERROR:  42883: function array_remove(bigint[], integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT array_remove(ARRAY[1::bigint], 1);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
LOCATION:  ParseFuncOrColumn, parse_func.c:523
```

---

```
[local] #= SELECT array_remove(ARRAY[1::bigint], 1::bigint);
┌──────────────┐
│ array_remove │
├──────────────┤
│ {}           │
└──────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, damn it was so simple :)